# Solving eigenvalue problem with a linear constraint

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I want to solve an eigenvalue problem with a linear constraint:
\begin{align}
\max \ & x^T A x &\\
\text{s.t.} \ & x^T x = 1& \\
& c^T x = b&\\
\end{align}

If $b = 0$, the solution can be found in [Golub 1973](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/1015032).

How can I solve the above problem when $b \neq 0$?

Comment: Since it has been 6 months and there's been no answers, comments, or upvotes, should we migrate this to Operations Research stack exchange, where optimization problems are solved regularly?